# Is it possible to programmatically set the state of a Jison parser in your JS code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing, state, jison

I'm writing a script in JS that utilizes Jison (https://zaa.ch/jison/) as the parser generator; I couldn't find anything in its docs that looks like the following:

```
// index.js - the script using the jison parser 

let myParser = require('/path/to/parser').parser; 

// some logic here to determine what the state should be 

myParser.setState('someState');
myParser.parser('someInput'); 
myParser.popState(); 

// etc.
```

I have some logic that cleans up responses from a server and determines some information about that output prior to sending it to my parser. Is it possible to set my parser's state outside of the `.jison` file itself?

Thanks!

---

**Edit:** adding more info below:

I noticed in the code generated by Jison, the parser function/object being exported has a `lexer` field. The lexer has methods `pushState()` and `popState()`. I tried calling that, but I get the following error:

Example:

```
let myParser = require('/path/to/parser').parser; 

myParser.lexer.pushState('someState');
myParser.parse('someInput');
myParser.lexer.popState();
```

Output:

```
node index.js
C:\path\to\my\script\TheParser.js:608
        this.conditionStack.push(condition);
                            ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `begin`/`pushState` before the lexer has been initialised, which happens when its `setInput` method is called. I guess you could call that method yourself, although the parser will call it again regardless.

Comment: That makes sense - thanks for the help. I've come up with a way to parse what I need without needing to set the state ahead of time; I'll remember this next time I attempt a solution like this!